# Anti matter elements?

Tags: exotic-atoms

Quite a self-explanatory question I guess. I wonder whether there is any information or theory on this. I seem to like remember there is such an element with positron in center and electron rotating around but nothing else.

Can there be any use if we somehow get these? Don't think like immediate destruction, the electrostatic force between "normal" elements electron and the other types can still repel each other and prevent immediate annihilation, in my view.

Can there be any spot in universe with mostly antimatter?

Comment: Whether/where/how stabke antimatter is, is more of a physics questions. But assuming sufficient short time scales or stable antimatter, you can apply the very same quantum chemical methods to describe the chemistry of such elements. The one you are refering to is conveniently called positronium, and can be considered an excotic, super light weight hydrogen isotop

Comment: anti-hydrogen consists of an anti-proton with a *positron* in orbit. Not a positron and en electron. A positron is the anti-particle of the electron not the proton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antihydrogen has been made at CERN in small amounts.

This is made by the alpha experiment, from poistrons and antiprotons. So far they have not been able to do any chemistry experiments.

https://home.cern/about/experiments/alpha
https://home.cern/about/engineering/storing-antimatter

Comment: But also they have not observed any notable differences between the properties and the properties of normal matter. So it looks like chemistry would be the same.

Answer (score 6):

There is no theory, nor is there a need for one. To put in in other words: yes, there is a theory, and that's the one you are already familiar with. Antimatter elements are precisely the same as ordinary matter elements, only the other way around. There ***"are"*** (read: ***"could be"***, though some were actually detected) antihydrogen, antihelium (all with the same energy levels as their real counterparts), also anticarbon, antiwater, anti-$\ce{NaCl}$, antiglucose, and pretty much everything anty-else.

To compose a substance of *particles and antiparticles together* is an entirely different question. Yes, there is a compound of electron and positron; it is called [positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium) and has the lifetime of a few microseconds or something. Electrostatic forces **attract** the opposite particles, rather than repel them (otherwise it would not be a compound, BTW), so it annihilates pretty quickly. There are other similar compounds, equally or more short-lived. Matter and antimatter do not sit well with each other; there is no going around it.

As for the spots of the Universe composed of antimatter, there was once a mainstream view that there must be many of those, about as many as those made of matter. Then the global symmetry broke, and things went... complicated. I'd rather leave it at that. Go ask at Phys.SE for a more comprehensive take.

So it goes.